# What happens if I call password_verify() with corrupted parameters?

Tags: php, parameters, sanitization

According to [its documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) PHP's `password_verify()` function

> Returns TRUE if the password and hash match, **or FALSE otherwise.** 
>    *[highlight added by me]*

The documentation also indicates that the functions parameters are:

> `password` The user's password.
>
> `hash` A hash created by password_hash().

The documentation does not provide any insight about *errors*/*exceptions*/*warning* with respect to cases in which those parameters are "corrupted" or invalid.

Some quick testing showed me that the question is rather tolerant with regard to "garbage" being passed in (especiallty in the `hash` parameter). My question is if I can rely on this behavior, as it would be somewhat implied in the "Returns[...]or FALSE otherwise" part?

Comment: Function checks if two values are equal. What exceptions do you want? Values either equal or not.

Comment: @u_mulder My worry, a) to receive false positive with garbled `hash` parameter and b) to receive a dreaded *exception*/*warning*/*error_reporting*-y stuff.   Maybe the documentation would however explicitly any exceptions that could occur when calling a function?

Comment: Still unclear, what the profit of exception/error?

Comment: @u_mulder I see your point and the tested behavior to return false in cases where the provided `hash` is not even in the correct form, fits my application, the main concern remaining is however any unforeseen expections. The documentation is not very exhaustive at that point. It does not mention any potential exceptions/warning/errors, which is why I'd rather ask here, before problems occur in the application.

Comment: If you afraid of exceptions - wrap in try-catch block. But as nothing is described in a manual - I suppose there're no exceptions.

Comment: I would have added that "`@` shut-up-prefix", but then again if it cannot fail? If only the documentation was telling the what happens in cases in which the inputs are not as clearly foreseen.

Comment: I still don;t know why you need exceptions here. Thousand of people use this without exceptions. One reason is to not throw exception is prevent timing attacks. I'm sure you can use this function without hesitation about exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PHP document: if no exception/error/warning is mentioned, then there will be no exception/error/warning. If you meet an exception without any document, it is a BUG in the document, and you can report it to the PHP team to fix it. So writing a clean `if (!password_verify(...))` is OK.

For `password_verify`: it is meaningless to distinguish invalid hash or wrong password for password verification, so `password_verify` just returns `false` if the hash doesn't match the password. Such behavior makes programming easier.

Comment: Also considering [@u_mulder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553888/u-mulder) comments to the question above, mentioning "timing attacks", make it reasonable that `password_verify()` would not generate exceptions. However I assume that siliently returning `false` in cases where the hash is not fitting, because of its form might silently hide this form the developer, which makes programming somewhat harder too. Thanks however for also mentioning how to interpret the PHP documentation, with regards to exceptions